# Homebrew: Pre-downloading a file for a formula

Tags: macos, installation, homebrew

I was trying to install `gtk` via Homebrew, and one of the steps was to install `glib`. Due to the poor internet environment, the files cannot be accessed by Homebrew. As told in https://docs.brew.sh/Tips-N%27-Tricks#pre-downloading-a-file-for-a-formula, I downloaded `glib-2.62.3.tar.xz` manually, and renamed it to `/Users/username/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/1ceb5460421ff37cf2c270573cd81d23a3fc0629114ebe78eee705acbd80c9e7--glib-2.62.3.tar.xz`, which is the output of `brew --cache -s glib`.

However, as I run `brew install glib` again, the message was:

```
==> Downloading https://download.gnome.org/sources/glib/2.62/glib-2.62.3.tar.xz
Already downloaded: /Users/xwm/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/1ceb5460421ff37cf2c270573cd81d23a3fc0629114ebe78eee705acbd80c9e7--glib-2.62.3.tar.xz
==> Downloading https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/61642
curl: (7) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443: Connection refused

Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  DownloadError: Failed to download resource "glib--patch"
Download failed: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/formula-patches/6164294a7/glib/hardcoded-paths.diff
```

Although this file can be retrived manually, by this time I have no idea how to reaname it so as to be recongnized by Homebrew. How should I proceed?